# How to free memory allocated in a function

Tags: c, unix, memory, malloc, free

As in subject of this topic. I have a simple function:

```
char *to_str(int x)
{
    char *s = malloc(6);

    if (s == NULL) {
        error("malloc");
    }

    snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "%d", x);
    return s;
}
```

which is allocating memory in its body, and returning such value. How should I handle memory deallocation? What would be the best approach?

Comment: What you allocate with `malloc` you shall free with `free`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should I handle memory deallocation?

Carefully. And definitely better than you do currently.

> What would be the best approach?

The best approach is to `free()` the memory when you don't need it anymore:

```
char *str = to_str(1337);
// do stuff with `str'
free(str);
```

Also, that `sizeof()` is wrong. It gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer. You need to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @NPE Thanks. I had to look up that song, and there's indeed some similarity.

Comment: Personally I don't like to write "`sizeof()`" (with parenthesis), because then, it looks like a function. Why not "`sizeof`"? But +1 anyway.

Comment: @Kirilenko Yes, parentheses are not always needed for this operator. But it's just in some sidenote anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The calling code needs to free the memory using `free()`:

```
void f(int x)
{
    char *s = to_str(x);
    // ...
    free(s);
}
```

(By the way, you have a bug: in `to_str`, `sizeof(s)` is the size of a pointer, not the length of the string that `s` points to.)

Comment: but it is char* (function)...
the question look to be rather to ask, where is the best idea to deallocate...

Comment: @V-X What are you even talking about? This answer is correct!

Comment: @V-X: I understand neither your comment nor your downvote - could you explain in more detail where I've misunderstood?

Comment: The question was about passing pointer outside of a function and you've proposed function, which is not returning anything. size_of is the only good point of this answer.

Comment: @V-X: You have misunderstood my answer.  The function in my answer is code that calls the function in the question, `to_str`, and then frees the memory that it returns.

Answer (score 0):

The first of all, `sizeof()` is an operator that gives you a length in bytes of type (type of variable) in brackets. Thus instead of actual length of the allocated memory block, you are getting a size of the pointer `s`, that in common not what you expect.

The second, when you allocating the memory, you should understand the moment when it is not actually used and to make `free()` on it.

Also, I am not sure that `5` symbols + terminating `0` is an enough length of the string, as in case of the garbage in the `x` the string will be much longer, so you can corrupt the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The best is not to allocate memory inside function:

```
 char* to_str(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size, int x);
```

this way you don't have to care about deallocation inside the function and everything is on the caller side.

If you want to create function with the signature you have in the question, you cannot use that in anything like `printf("%s", to_str(x))`, because this would be a memory leak. You have to make `char *str = to_str(x); printf("%s", str); free(str);` which is not nice...